# linear interpolation between two data points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have two data points `x` and `y`:

```
  x = 5 (value corresponding to 95%)
  y = 17 (value corresponding to 102.5%)
```

No I would like to calculate the value for `xi` which should correspond to 100%.

```
 x = 5 (value corresponding to 95%)
 xi = ?? (value corresponding to 100%)
 y = 17 (value corresponding to 102.5%)
```

How should I do this using python?

Comment: Off-topic: Note that you are literally asking for linear interpolation. When collecting real life data distribution will not necessarily be linear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [145]: s = pd.Series([5, np.nan, 17], index=[95, 100, 102.5])

In [146]: s
Out[146]:
95.0      5.0
100.0     NaN
102.5    17.0
dtype: float64

In [147]: s.interpolate(method='index')
Out[147]:
95.0      5.0
100.0    13.0
102.5    17.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: 11 is not the correct result although the solution looks correct. is there something wrong with the interpolate function?

Comment: @Al_Iskander pass `method='index'` if you want it to take index into account.

Comment: @MaxU I've edited to change the default parameter. The default version ignores the index (assumes equidistance I think).

Comment: @ayhan, thanks a lot for the correction! I was offline a couple of hours...

Answer (score 15):

You can use [numpy.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) function to interpolate a value

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [95, 102.5]
y = [5, 17]

x_new = 100

y_new = np.interp(x_new, x, y)
print(y_new)
# 13.0

plt.plot(x, y, "og-", x_new, y_new, "or");
```

[image]

Comment: How to use interp to a data frame where I would like to interpolate some missing values based on cell from same column but rows above and below? I suppose I need to use shift method.
Here is my separate [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63279957/interpolate-between-two-nearby-rows-of-dataframe)

Comment: Great solution. Interp even works if you provide an entire array for x_new. This way I was able to synchronize two entire datasets.

Answer (score 9):

We can easily plot this on a graph without Python:

[image]

This shows us what the answer should be (13).

But how do we calculate this? First, we find the gradient with this:

[image]

The numbers substituted into the equation give this:

[image]

So we know for 0.625 we increase the Y value by, we increase the X value by 1.

We've been given that Y is 100. We know that 102.5 relates to 17. `100 - 102.5 = -2.5`. `-2.5 / 0.625 = -4` and then `17 + -4 = 13`.

This also works with the other numbers: `100 - 95 = 5`, `5 / 0.625 = 8`, `5 + 8 = 13`.

We can also go backwards using the reciprocal of the gradient (`1 / m`).

We've been given that X is 13. We know that 102.5 relates to 17. `13 - 17 = -4`. `-4 / 0.625 = -2.5` and then `102.5 + -2.5 = 100`.

How do we do this in python?

```
def findXPoint(xa,xb,ya,yb,yc):
    m = (xa - xb) / (ya - yb)
    return (yc - yb) * m + xb
```

And to find a Y point given the X point:

```
def findYPoint(xa,xb,ya,yb,xc):
    m = (ya - yb) / (xa - xb)
    return (xc - xb) * m + yb
```

This function will also extrapolate from the data points.

Comment: See The 1st answer using pandas series, it got 11 for input 100

Comment: indeed strange. I was first accepting because the solution looked formally correct but the result 11 is not correct and 13 is better.

Comment: @Al_Iskander Yes, his answer does get it wrong, which is strange. My answer works, but is not the best - a builtin function would be better.

Comment: AFAIK, normally "gradient" refers to delta y / delta x. The reciprocal of the gradient would be the other way around (dX/dY). Of course what the OP needed was the reciprocal gradient which you gave him.