# how to create new column based on multiple columns with a function

Tags: python, function, pandas, vectorization

This question is following up to my questionabout [linear interpolation between two data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282659/linear-interpolation-between-two-data-points/38282695?noredirect=1#comment63984980_38282695this)

I built following function from it:

```
def inter(colA, colB):
   s = pd.Series([colA, np.nan, colB], index= [95, 100, 102.5])
   s = s.interpolate(method='index')
   return s.iloc[1]
```

Now I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
           on95   on102.5   on105
Index
  1         5       17        20
  2         7       15        25
  3         6       16        23
```

I would like to create a new column `df['new']` that uses the function `inter` with inputs of `on95` and `on102.5`

I tried like this:

```
df['new'] = inter(df['on95'],df['on102.5'])
```

but this resulted in NaN's.

I also tried with `apply(inter)` but did not find a way to make it work without an error message.

Any hints how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to vectorize your self defined function with `np.vectorize`, since the function parameters are accepted as pandas Series:

```
inter = np.vectorize(inter)
df['new'] = inter(df['on95'],df['on102.5'])
df

            on95    on102.5 on105         new
#Index              
#   1          5        17    20    13.000000
#   2          7        15    25    12.333333
#   3          6        16    23    12.666667
```